# How to handle delete in messaging system? (insufficient answers)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**My Sql Table**

> 1. message_id
> 2. sender_id
> 3. receiver_id
> 4. subject
> 5. message
> 6. status

I have created a `mysql` database for an internal messaging system.

In my DB structure there is table for messages in which each message has the sender user_id and receiver user_id. An inbox of any user can populate according to their own id relation as receiver_id in messages table.
My problem is when I try to delete any message, so that message are gone from both the end sender & receiver.

question:

**So is there any alternate solution in which the message is removed from only those user who performed the delete operation.**

**My İnbox my_id(1):**

```
sender_id (2)--subject--message [Delete button](*deletion is done with message id*)
----------------------------------------
```

**Other User id(2) sent box:**

```
receiver_id(1)--subject--message
--------------
```

sql code of messages I have listed in my inbox

```
$id=$userRow["user_id"];
$stmt = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id=$id ORDER BY message_id DESC  ");
$stmt->execute();
```

I haven't been able to find answers in previous questions, they seem to be error-prone so I re-opened this question.

---note that too many users are messaging

I thank all the users for their efforts

**my language is not english so i am sorry if i made a mistake**

Comment: `My problem is when I try to delete any message, so that message are gone from both the end sender & receiver.` -> so what;s the actual problem? What do you expect

Comment: Welcome. Keep track of who deleted the message in a separate table.

Comment: personally i wouldn't delete either. Set a DeletedOn date to current time, when the user deletes. Deleteing on message id alone isn't good, because it sounds like you only want to delete the message for the user that is currently logged in. Your app should know if they're the sender or the receiver so delete accordingly

Comment: "_The answers given in the previous topics are error-prone so I re-opened this topic_" o-O so you've deleted the efforts of the previous users instead to try to explain in it more consistently what doesn't go for you?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstandings, I respect everyone's efforts

Comment: @Junno The problem is not your english. Deleting a question to repost it is a very bad and discouraged pratice by SO for obvious reasons. Take some time to read the help section to avoid this type of problems in the future. I could help to improve your questions but without seeing it is impossible for me/us :-)

Comment: I find your criticism correct but I did a lot of research . couldn't find the appropriate answer.So I didn't want to waste too much time.I respect all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two more fields in your table for delete status:

1. deleted_for_sender, `default(0) or NULL`
2. deleted_for_receiver, `default(0) or NULL`

When sender deletes the message set the `deleted_for_sender = 1`, or when receiver deletes the message, change status `deleted_for_receiver = 1`.

Now when you want messages list for receiver try as below example:

```
$id=$userRow["user_id"];
$stmt = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id=$id AND deleted_for_receiver != 1 ORDER BY message_id DESC  ");
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
// do something with $row
}
```

And messages list for sender as below:

```
$id=$userRow["user_id"];
$stmt = $baglanti->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id=$id AND deleted_for_sender != 1 ORDER BY message_id DESC  ");
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
// do something with $row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new status column("deleted_by" or you can set whatever you want to say it) in your message table and when someone perform delete operation just change value(0 as default value, 1 if deleted by sender, 2 if deleted by reciever and 3 if deleted by both) of that status column instead of deleting the row.

Comment: I don't know about it, so I'm asking : If there are too many users, won't the messages damage the sql table?

Comment: I don't think it is easy for simple app to cross MySQL table's row limit [read more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html). You can delete rows which status code is 3 (if you use status code as I mentioned above) and archieve old messages in different table.

Comment: it seems very logical,I will try this,Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting message row from table you can also able to take status code field for into table

0-no
1-deleted by sender
2-deleted by receiver

Comment: If there are too many users, won't the messages damage the sql table?

Comment: I'm talking about personal messaging